# Create an account every time a contact is created (and the account is not existing in the Org)

Tags: trigger, dmlexception

I have a requirement to create a new account(if the entered account doesn't exist already) every time a contact is created/edited from ETL (The ETL profile user)

```
public static void createAutoVendor(List<Contact> contList, boolean isInsert, boolean isUpdate, Map<Id, Contact> oldContacts){
    Set<Id> existingAccs = New Set<Id>();
    Set<String> existingAccNames = New Set<String>();
    List<Account> newAccs = New List<Account>();
    Map<String, Id> mapAccToCont = New Map<String, Id>();
    Id createdBy=[SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Name  = 'ETL User'].id;
            
    //Select all the existing Accounts and add them to the Set of Accounts
    for (Account acc:[SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]){
        existingAccs.add(acc.id);
        existingAccNames.add(acc.Name);
    }
    for (Contact con:contList){
        if(con.Vendor__c <> null){  //Vendor__c is the name of the account in ETL

            if(((isInsert && con.CreatedById==createdBy) ||
               (isUpdate && con.LastModifiedById==createdBy 
                && con.Vendor__c<>oldContacts.get(con.Id).Vendor__c))
              && (!existingAccNames.contains(con.Vendor__c))){
                   Account Acc = New Account(name=con.Vendor__c, Type='Vendor'); //Create a new Account if it's not existing already
                   newAccs.add(Acc);

               }
            insert newAccs;

        }            
    }
    for (Account acc:newAccs){
        mapAccToCont.put(acc.Name, acc.Id);

    }
    for (Contact con:contList){
        if(mapAccToCont.containsKey(con.Vendor__c)){
            con.AccountId=mapAccToCont.get(con.Vendor__c);

        }
    }        
}
```

This code is working when I am running from the "Execute Anonymous Window" as an Admin. But failing from ETL with following error:
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, ContactTrigger: execution of BeforeInsert

Any help in this regard is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems in your code. You have a DML statement in a for loop, you have an unrestricted query, and your code will insert duplicate vendors if not found in the database in the same transaction.

What you need is the [Query-Aggregate-Update pattern](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html).

Here's a revised version of your method:

```
public static void assignVendors(Contact[] newContacts, Contact[] oldContacts) {
    // Aggregate
    Map<String, Id> vendorIdByName = new Map<String, Id>();
    Contact[] affectedContacts = new Contact[0];
    for(Integer i = 0, s = newContacts.size(); i < s; i++) {
        Contact oldContact = oldContacts?.get(i);
        Contact newContact = newContacts[i];
        if(oldContact?.Vendor__c != newContact.Vendor__c) {
            vendorIdByName.put(newContact.Vendor__c, null);
            affectedContacts.add(newContact);
        }
    }
    if(vendorIdByName.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    // Query
    for(Account vendorRecord: [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name = :vendorIdByName.keySet() AND Type = 'Vendor']) {
        vendorIdByName.put(vendorRecord.Name, vendorRecord.Id);
    }
    // Updates
    Account[] newVendors = new Account[0];
    for(String vendorName: vendorIdByName.keySet()) {
        if(vendorIdByName.get(vendorName) == null) {
            newVendors.add(new Account(Name=vendorName, Type='Vendor'));
        }
    }
    insert newVendors;
    for(Account vendorRecord: newVendors) {
        vendorIdByName.put(vendorRecord.Name, vendorRecord.Id);
    }
    for(Contact contactRecord: affectedContacts) {
        contactRecord.AccountId = vendorIdByName.get(contactRecord.Vendor__c);
    }
}
```

Note the use of `?.`, the Safe Navigation Operator, to reduce the number of if statements we need, the use of appropriate filters to make sure we find the correct vendor accounts, terminating early if we don't have any updates to do, moving the DML operation outside the loop, the use of a Set (via the Map) so we don't create duplicate vendors, and leveraging a separate list so we don't have to process every record more than necessary.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @sfdcfox. I'm currently trying to go thru your code and implement. I will let you know asap.
Really appreciate your time and effort.